# Unit Testing $scope.$on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Hello Everyone I am struggling at testing a $.on function and I am looking for any suggestions or help on this:

**controller**

```
  $scope.$on("sampleFilesSelected", function(event, args) {
                $scope.sampleFiles = args.newSampleFiles;
            });
```

**spec**

```
describe('Testing a $.on', function() {
  var $scope = null;
  var ctrl = null;


  beforeEach(module('test'));

  it('should invoke myEvent when "myEvent" broadcasted', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();

    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });

    $scope.$broadcast('myEvent');
    expect($scope.sampleFilesSelected).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

**error**

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'newSampleFiles' of undefined or null reference
        undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass a value to your event, call a $digest before your assertion :

```
$scope.$broadcast('myEvent', { 'newSampleFiles' : true } );
$scope.$digest();
expect($scope.sampleFilesSelected).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code ...

```
$scope.$broadcast('myEvent');
```

is not passing any args and so args.newSampleFiles throws an error because args is undefined

you need to pass args - how you do that I don't know

However, I would say ... unit testing is used for testing controller code not really for testing event handling. Your example is a bit of an edge case. I would be tempted to test the event handling use E2E testing and protractor.

I would refactor as follows ...

```
$scope.$on("sampleFilesSelected", function(event, args) {
                $scope.sampleFiles = args.newSampleFiles;
            });
```

would become ...

```
$scope.myFunction = function(event, args) {
   $scope.sampleFiles = args.newSampleFiles;
}

$scope.$on("sampleFilesSelected", $scope.myFunction);
```

and i would unit test $scope.myFunction. And leave the testing of $scope.$on to E2E protractor testing.

Hope that helps

Comment: I will agree this is a better way to write it.

Comment: its not meant to be a better way to write it - its to allow it to be unit tested without relying on events firing - the events themselves can be tested in protractor

Answer (score 1):

You're making three mistakes, first one being is that you're listening/subscribing to a event named `sampleFilesSelected` in your controller but in your test, you're broadcasting to anyone that's listening to an event called `myEvent`?

Secondly, once above is fixed, you should run `$scope.$digest()` cycle after you trigger an event and then you can follow it up with your `expect(...)`.

Third, as mentioned by others, you should pass the data as second arg when $broadcast ...ing!